# Welcome message with user avatar for Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on a Discord bot with JavaScript and I want to get a welcome message with the user image (like [this](https://ibb.co/dEYXXK)). I have no idea of where should I start, could someone help me?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you tried reading Discord's API docs?

Comment: Add a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you tried so far

Comment: i´ve tried nothing yet, i have no ideia how i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event that is triggered every time a new member joins the guild is [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd), emitted by the client.
To send the image, you can either send it as an [`Attachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) or as the image of a [`RichEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=image).

In order to do all this stuff, you'll need something like this:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  // channel: the channel you want to send the welcome message in

  // you can either send a normal message:
  channel.send(`Welcome ${member}, bla bla bla...`, { // its like sending a normal message, but with some MessageOptions
    file: 'https://image.ibb.co/dNGVKz/Screenshot_1.png' // this is your image URL
  });

  // or send it with an embed:
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Welcome")
    .setDescription(`Hi ${member}, bla bla bla...`)
    .setImage('https://image.ibb.co/dNGVKz/Screenshot_1.png');
  channel.send({embed});
});
```

If there's some methods or classes that you don't know yet, you can look them up in the [wiki](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).